# Why does /^[\s]* not work how I expect?

Tags: regular-expression

I use `vim` as my `$MANPAGER`. I will often use `:/^[ ]*-F` (for example) to quickly jump to a flag and read up on it. However, the equivalent `:/^[\s]*-F` doesn't return the same results.
Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character classes such as `\s` for spaces or `\d` for digits do not work inside a `[ ]` collection in the Vim flavor of regexp. So `[\s]` is actually matching either a backslash or a lowercase "s".

But in your case, you don't need a `[ ]` collection anyways, because the `\s` is the only thing you're matching there.

So this should work just fine:

```
/^\s*-F
```

One alternative is to use a full character class expression (not one using the `\`-letter shorthand notation, but the `[:class:]` one), in which case `/^[[:blank:]]*-F` is what you want here (`[:blank:]` is the one matching a space or a tab, same as `\s`.)

Comment: "do not work inside a `[ ]` group".... does this pertain to all of the characters at http://vimregex.com/#metacharacters and no others?

Comment: @alec It's complicated... Some such as `\t` will actually work inside `[ ]`. See `:help /[` for more details.

Comment: That's confusing, I've only really ever seen character classes written inside square brackets. Thanks for the quick and informative reply.